# How to scrape a news feed?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have been going through the `Scrapy` examples and they make sense, but as soon as I try it on a news feed I don't get anything but titles and don't know how to proceed.

```
scrapy shell http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml
```

All I can get from this is

```
response.xpath('//title')
```

Which outputs

```
<Selector xpath='//title' data=u'<title xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.'>]
```

How can I possible find the tags inside?

When I try this:

```
response.xpath('//div')
```

it returns null. I have tried Inspect Elements from Chome to check the content, but I can't somehow even get to the body to try out things. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with the "tags"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rss` is not an `html` document, it is `xml` document. You can find info on `rss` at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_rss.asp. `rss` documents look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">

<channel>
  <title>W3Schools Home Page</title>
  <link>http://www.w3schools.com</link>
  <description>Free web building tutorials</description>
  <item>
    <title>RSS Tutorial</title>
    <link>http://www.w3schools.com/rss</link>
    <description>New RSS tutorial on W3Schools</description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>XML Tutorial</title>
    <link>http://www.w3schools.com/xml</link>
    <description>New XML tutorial on W3Schools</description>
  </item>
</channel>

</rss>
```

So there are no `div` tags in it. To get description of each post/news you can use `response.xpath('//description/text()')`

Scrapy docs can be found here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html